# Find 2d array inside a 3d array

Tags: python, arrays, performance, numpy, search

Is there a fast way to find all indices where a 2d array is inside a 3d array?

I have this 3d numpy array:

```
arr = np.array([
        [[0,1],[0,2],[0,3],[0,4],[0,4],[0,5],[0,5],[0,5],[0,5],[0,5]],
        [[0,1],[0,2],[0,2],[0,2],[0,3],[0,4],[0,4],[0,4],[0,5],[0,5]],
        [[0,1],[0,2],[0,3],[0,3],[0,3],[0,4],[0,4],[0,5],[0,5],[0,5]]
       ])
```

And I would like to find all indices where `[0,4]` occurs.
I've tried this one:

```
whereInd = np.argwhere(arr == np.array([0,4]))
```

but it doesn't work. 
The expected result is:

```
[[0 3],[0 4],[1 5],[1 6],[1 7],[2 5],[2 6]]
```

Another question is, will this be fast? Because I would like to use it for a `(10000,100,2)` array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `argwhere()` is a good idea, but you also need to use `all()` to get your desired output:

```
>>> np.argwhere((arr == [0, 4]).all(axis=2))
array([[0, 3],
       [0, 4],
       [1, 5],
       [1, 6],
       [1, 7],
       [2, 5],
       [2, 6]])
```

Here `all()` is used to check each row is `[True, True]` following the comparison (that is, the row is equal to `[0, 4]`). In a 3D array, `axis=2` points along rows.

This reduces the number of dimensions to two, and `argwhere()` returns the desired array of indices.

---

Regarding performance, this method should handle arrays of the size you specify fairly quickly:

```
In [20]: arr = np.random.randint(0, 10, size=(10000, 100, 2))
In [21]: %timeit np.argwhere((arr == [0, 4]).all(axis=2))
10 loops, best of 3: 44.9 ms per loop
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution I can think of is:

```
import numpy as np
arr = np.array([
        [[0,1],[0,2],[0,3],[0,4],[0,4],[0,5],[0,5],[0,5],[0,5],[0,5]],
        [[0,1],[0,2],[0,2],[0,2],[0,3],[0,4],[0,4],[0,4],[0,5],[0,5]],
        [[0,1],[0,2],[0,3],[0,3],[0,3],[0,4],[0,4],[0,5],[0,5],[0,5]]
       ])

whereInd = []
for i,row in enumerate(arr):
    for j,elem in enumerate(row):
        if all(elem == [0,4]):
            whereInd.append((i,j))

print whereInd
#prints [(0, 3), (0, 4), (1, 5), (1, 6), (1, 7), (2, 5), (2, 6)]
```

Although any solution with `np.argwhere` should work around 10 times faster.